# Is there a Collection of icons used for imageMso?

Tags: excel, vba, office-addins, excel-addins, ribbonx

I started to write an add-in for searching and viewing built in icons/images (imageMso) for the Office Fluent ribbon to find something suitable to add to new buttons. Yes, I know there are many out there, but I haven't found any particularly useful yet. I end up spending hours or days trying to find something that fits a purpose.

Does anyone know how the icons are stored or where they come from? Are they in a collection that is accessible and could be looped through along the lines of...?

```
For each img in imageMso
```

Loading them in manually, I have come up against a size limitation in VBA for the size of individual modules so would need to have many modules, then re-write when each version of office is released.

Comment: Maybe of interest though you probably have alreadt seen: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.getimagemso?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaof11.chm2025)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue   ; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb187398(v=office.12)

Answer (score 8):

YES.  There is a comprehensive Icon Gallery complete with control ID published by Microsoft here: [2010 MS Office Gallery](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21103)

Once the file is downloaded, then Click to enable "edit".
Next, in the Ribbon, Click on: **File**-->, then **Info**.  You'll then see ***"ImageMso 0"*** and ***ImageMso 1***.  Click on either to get the Gallery of iso Images for you to review.

[image]
Screen Shot of ISO Image Gallery in MS Word.
[image]

Sorry for the belated answer

Comment: This is awesome!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

May this link help to viewing built in icons/images (imageMso) for the Office Fluent ribbon to find something
https://bert-toolkit.com/imagemso-list.html#MeetingRequest

Answer (score -1):

Just for future reference, there is no imageMso collection available in Office. Neither will you find a definitive id list. You will have to side load custom UI control IDs and iterate over them yourself. As of today this might be the most up-to-date list:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/fe2124a1-5aaa-4adf-b285-5d58da9d5e2a

Also, be aware that the IDs might change with each new office version. Some get added, some are obsoleted.